# Specializing new

Tags: c++, clang

I want to implement my own version of `new` in C++ that takes an allocator. I am able to do this with:

```
template <class T>
void *operator new(std::size_t size, project::specialized_allocator<T> &a) {
  return a.allocate(size);
}
```

I can then use this allocator with:

```
project::specialized_allocator<int> A;
int *i = new (A) int;
```

However, I can also call:

```
int *i = new (nullptr) int;
```

And Clang doesn't complain but compiles the code. I'm not sure what this is supposed to do & why it's not failing to compile with a type error. `nullptr` isn't a `project::specialized_allocator<T> &`.

I get a similar weirdness with:

```
int *i = new (i) int;
```

How is that supposed to work? And why aren't these examples failing to type check?

Comment: In my opinion, messing around with `operator new` is misguided. The standard library takes the right approach by allowing allocators for all sorts of constructions (containers, smart pointers), and that's saner. You shouldn't be saying `new` in your code anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an existing [`placement new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) operator that takes a `void*` or a `std:nothrow_t` as its second parameter.

The first is meant for allocating an object at an existing memory address.  That is why `new (nullptr)` and `new (i)` compile, since they are both convertible to `void*`.

The second is for telling the standard allocation to return a NULL pointer instead of throwing a `std::bad_alloc` exception if the allocation fails.

You can define your other parameters, but you have to make sure any parameters you do pass are convertible to your parameter types and not to `void*` or `std::nothrow_t`, otherwise the standard operators will be called instead of your custom operator.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is correct. when `operator new` is found in the class, should it then consider any other at all? lemme check.

Comment: Ah, so `i` is getting converted to a `void*`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not implementing `operator new` inside a class, but at the top-level.

Comment: @oconnor0: ok then try placing it in the class. note that you can inherit it in.

Comment: I don't want to put it in a class. I want it to be at the top-level to be available for all uses.

Comment: it is available for all uses when it's in a class. it's just not contaminating the global namespace.

Comment: @Alf I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Individual classes can override `placement new`, but that means you have to override it in individual classes.  You can't implement `new` in one class and use it to allocate another class. The OP wants to be able to allocate multiple types with the new allocator.

Comment: well it's not easily available for allocating non-class items. but then that's not a good idea. you need to ensure that a corresponding `operator delete` is used, and in a class you can control this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: re "You can't implement new in one class and use it to allocate another class", yes you can. You can just inherit it in. As already stated.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: if you implement `T::operator new()`, how would you invoke it when creating a new instance of `X` instead of `T`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: re "otherwise the standard operators will be called instead of your custom operator.", only if one directly or indirectly includes the `<new>` header. apparently the OP's code does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that's trivial, you write `new (args) X`, and it will automatically use the allocation function that `X` inherits from `T`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That assumes `X` inherits from `T`. I don't want to have that requirement.

Comment: @oconnor0: it would **not** be a good idea to allocate instances of the same class in different ways, at least not when the allocator functions have correpsonding distinct deallocation functions. and debugging is best handled in other ways. but of course it's your code, and if you want bugs to bite you at inconvenient moments, well now you know one way to arrange that.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're using is called [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html), and the argument to `new` is supposed to be a pointer.  Placement new doesn't actually allocate anything; it just constructs an object at the location you specified.

When you write `new (nullptr)` you're telling it to construct an object at address 0, and `new (i)` is constructing it at an address taken from an uninitialized pointer.  Both of these cause undefined behavior at runtime, since they involve dereferencing null and uninitialized pointers.

Comment: re "the argument to new is supposed to be a pointer", no that isn't so.

Comment: Would it be better to say "typically"?  Most examples of placement new on the web are passing a pointer as the "place", and the standard overloads of operator new only support passing a `void*`.

Comment: The second parameter can be a `std::nothrow_t` or user-defined.  I have never seen a user-defined parameter used in real code, but I have seen (and myself used) the `nothrow` version.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking of the `nothrow` overload as "placement", though it does use the same syntax.

Comment: An allocation function can have any number of arguments >1. Thus, the phrase "the second parameter" implies a restriction that isn't there. The C++ standard places the following requirements on the declaration of an allocation function, whether global or class member: "The return type shall be void*. The first parameter shall have type std::size_t. The first parameter shall not have an associated default argument".

Comment: The allocation function *arguments* specified in a `new`-expression can be of any types, and of any number. When you use some specific allocation function then the arguments must match that function (with first argument value supplied by the `new` expression machinery). That's all.